# Why is Bash handling child processes different compared to Sh

Tags: bash, docker, sh, child-process, tini

The [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) init-process, used in Docker, mentions that process group killing is not activated by default and gives the following example:

```
docker run krallin/ubuntu-tini sh -c 'sleep 10'
```

If I run this, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> immediately after, I indeed have to wait for 10 seconds till the child process exits.

However, if instead of `sh` I used `bash`:

```
docker run krallin/ubuntu-tini bash -c 'sleep 10'
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, the process exits immediately.

Why do `sh` (which is symlinked to `dash`) and `bash` behave differently towards this child process?
And how does Bash kill the child process, I thought Bash does not propagate signals by default?

Comment: I belive `bash` is optimized to use `exec` to replace itself when possible. In this case, the simple command `sleep` replaces `bash`. `dash`, on the other hand, may simply be forking a new process and waiting on it, allowing it to respond to the signal.

Comment: If that's the case (which is likely), `sh -c 'exec sleep 10'` will make behavior consistent.

Comment: @Peter, btw, `bash -c 'sleep 10; exit'` will prevent this optimization: Because `sleep` is no longer the last command, the shell can no longer do an implicit `exec` of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered thanks to chepner and Charles Duffy:

`bash -c` has an implicit optimization where it uses `exec` to replace itself if possible. `sh` (`dash`) does not have this optimization. See also [this observation](https://lukeyeager.github.io/2019/11/05/bash-implicit-exec.html).

To verify:

- Process tree using `bash`:

```
❯ docker run --name test --rm --detach krallin/ubuntu-tini bash -c 'sleep 60'
03194d48a4dcc8225251fe1e5de2dcbb901c8a9cfd0853ae910bfe4d3735608d
❯ docker exec test ps axfo pid,ppid,args
    PID    PPID COMMAND
      1       0 /usr/bin/tini -- bash -c sleep 60
      7       1 sleep 60
```

- Process tree using `sh`:

```
❯ docker run --name test --rm --detach krallin/ubuntu-tini sh -c 'sleep 60'
e56f207509df4b0b57f8e6b2b2760835f6784a147b200d798dffad112bb11d6a
❯ docker exec test ps axfo pid,ppid,args
    PID    PPID COMMAND
      1       0 /usr/bin/tini -- sh -c sleep 60
      7       1 sh -c sleep 60
      8       7  \_ sleep 60
```

Comment: Well done. This is along the lines of the answer I was going to post, but couldn't remember the Docker incantation. (Oddly enough, I wasn't able to reproduce similar process trees *without* Docker, so I don't know if it was a difference between how `bash` and `dash` were compiled for this Docker image compared to the versions installed on my machine, or something else.)