# $PPID behavior of `bash -c` and `Dockerfile RUN`

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

This question has the same root cause as [Why is Bash handling child processes different compared to Sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827986/why-is-bash-handling-child-processes-different-compared-to-sh), but the symptom is largely different.

I knew that there is potential exec without fork when I asked this question (so I tried &, ; and ()), and I guessed this might be some optimization. However, since it is an undocumented feature, I can't confirm my assumption.

ChatGPT4 cannot correctly answer this question (with naive prompt) as well.

Thus, I will leave this question closed but not delete it.

---

Let's say there is a script named `echo-ppid.sh`

```bash
echo \$\$=$$ \$PPID=$PPID
```

I run the following script `test.sh` using `sh` or `bash` **on my host computer.**

```bash
echo $$

echo

sh echo-ppid.sh
sh -c 'sh echo-ppid.sh'
sh -c 'bash echo-ppid.sh'

echo

bash echo-ppid.sh
bash -c 'bash echo-ppid.sh'
bash -c 'sh echo-ppid.sh'

echo

bash -c '(bash echo-ppid.sh)'
bash -c '(sh echo-ppid.sh)'
```

I got

```
4027900

$$=4027901 $PPID=4027900
$$=4027903 $PPID=4027902
$$=4027905 $PPID=4027904

$$=4027906 $PPID=4027900
$$=4027907 $PPID=4027900
$$=4027908 $PPID=4027900

$$=4027910 $PPID=4027909
$$=4027914 $PPID=4027913
```

That is: `bash -c 'sh echo-ppid.sh'` has the same `$PPID` in `echo-ppid.sh` execution environment as `sh test.sh`, while `sh -c 'sh test.sh'` has a different `$PPID` as expected.

When I use `RUN ["sh", "test.sh"]` in Dockerfile(`FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.09-py3`), I got

```
$$=21 $PPID=1
$$=29 $PPID=1
$$=44 $PPID=1

$$=59 $PPID=1
$$=67 $PPID=1
$$=82 $PPID=1

$$=105 $PPID=97
$$=121 $PPID=113
```

I have tried

```
RUN ["sh", "echo-ppid.sh"]
RUN sh echo-ppid.sh
RUN sh -c "sh -c 'sh echo-ppid.sh'"
```

but got three `$$=1 $PPID=0`.

This is insane, and cause `ps -o comm $PPID` broken since `0` is out of range of PID.

For more information, I run

```
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "realpath /bin/sh"]
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "realpath /proc/$$/exe"]
```

I got

```
/usr/bin/sh-wrap
/usr/bin/realpath
```

It seems that the "`exec` optimization" mentioned by @Barmar is performed by `sh-wrap`.

On my host computer, `sh -c 'realpath /bin/bash'` gave me `/usr/bin/bash` and `sh -c 'realpath /proc/$$/exe'` gave me `/usr/bin/dash`.

Strangely, `RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "(ps -o comm 1)"]` gave

```
COMMAND
bash
```

and `RUN ["/bin/sh", "--version"]` (or run `/bin/sh --version` in container use the base image) gave

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Removing intermediate container a7d68de30cfd
```

(`dash` should give `/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --`)

It seems that in the base image `/bin/sh` is actually bash.

Comment: `in Dockerfile` What "Dockerfile"? What image? What `sh` is inside that image? `test.sh usingsh or bash` On your host computer? What is the output of `bash --version`? What is `sh` on your pc? Is `/usr/bin/sh` a symlink to ... ?

Comment: `bash` has an optimization where the last command in a script is executed with a simple `exec` rather than `fork+exec`. But putting it in `()` overrides that, and forces a subprocess to be forked.

Comment: The root cause is the same, but the symptom is much different. I knew that there is potential `exec` without `fork` when I asked the question (so I tried `&`, `;` and `()`), but it is hard to figure it out why there is no `fork`. ChatGPT4 cannot solve this problem as well.

Comment: BTW, keeping duplicative questions around is absolutely welcome when they pose a problem in a different way than the preexisting instances -- in fact, questions closed as duplicative can still be upvoted, despite being closed, because they make the canonical instances easier to find for people who might not recognize their problem as having a shared cause / being in fact the same thing without that duplicate acting as a "signpost" to show the way. So you absolutely don't need to defend your decision not to delete the question -- it's the right choice, clearly.